# Modify a Part of a RequestPart in Spring Boot 3 spring 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How do I modify a RequestPart before it reaches my handler method, i.e., how do I pass that modified attribute as a parameter before it reaches my PUT method?

code:

method put:

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@Valid @RequestPart("user") Usuario usuario, @RequestPart (value = "image",required = false) MultipartFile file,@PathVariable Long id){}
```

I tried to do it with an interceptor, but I can't figure out how to set that Part argument. There seems to be no way to modify Parts, only attributes.

my interceptor:

```
 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    
  ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
  Usuario usuario =  objectMapper.readValue(request.getPart("user").getInputStream(),Usuario.class);
            
  usuario.setEstadoConexion(true);
  request.setAttribute("user",usuario); // no pass
    
  return true;
 }
```

I expected my User-type Part to be passed as modified to the parameter of the Put method.